# matplotlib discrete bin plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

With discrete bin plot I refer to a type of plot which does not connect the points with a straight line, but uses a constant value for all the region which is closest to each point.

This is an example of this type of plot using PDL and PGPLOT.

```
pdl> use PDL::Graphics::PGPLOT;dev('/xs');$x=rint(grandom(20)*10);print $x;bin($x);hold;points($x,{color=>'red'})

[-19 -3 4 7 -8 -2 9 15 4 7 1 -14 -4 -4 11 6 -15 -13 2 1]Graphics on HOLD
```

[image]

This type of plot is sometimes useful.

I am interested in knowing a way to display this type of plot in matplotlib. I could not find a specific function.

Alternative ways to do it in matplotlib would also be useful as well as perhaps other packages for plotting in python. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [step plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html) in matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [-19, -3, 4, 7, -8, -2, 9, 15, 4, 7, 1, -14, -4, -4, 11, 6, -15, -13, 2, 1]
plt.step(range(len(y)), y, 'o-', where='mid')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! and the "where" option marks the location of the point within the "bin"?

Comment: yes - see linked docs